# Decode binary data returned from PDF417 barcode scanned with react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, decode, react-native-camera, pdf417

I'm building an small application with react native to read the barcode from an ID document, and extract the user information. I use react-native-camera to read the barcode successfully but now I need to decode the binary data. Here is a sample of what is returned when scanned:

`A10995848VISITOR000000000000889950JHONSMITH 19990525M201812156814O+US2FMR 20Ú±GôôÅÅP~Zú<Zê-àú-*òZäîF:wZà8[U"@~Z4æUîFjUBö6UFU¸ZÔHYZ:FZ¾äyZT&U¶¢ZP80UÚ¸aZ@ÂZ¦ZàldZÖ¦_UzZp"ZÞvZ,¤PX¾CU7FMR 20Ú±GôôÅÅPòUöPØ ZêU.Z$6xZBZºZÎ¡ZÖÔyUÜVZ<ÞZP8ZV Z$fZ´Þ~ZFÖZXðZ &Z$¸¦Zö®U>fZNVPÀjEU$~Ul0K¸¼tZ:~dPZ2Z¬hEU`

I can see the information I need, for example the birth date (19990525), names (JHON SMITH), document number (889950), but I can't see a way to isolate it.

Comment: When trying with different pdf documents: Does the binary data always look alike? I mean does it always have a pattern like this `....VISITOR000########{NAME}{SPACE}########M......` ?

Comment: We have to scan two types of documents: foreign and domestic. I believe all foreign documents have the same structure, and all domestic documents have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript with [js-zxing-pdf417](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/js-zxing-pdf417) . there is also a [demo](http://peculiarventures.github.io/js-zxing-pdf417/examples/zxing-pdf417-example1.html) for the project.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I uploaded a document to the demo page, but the still can't get the information. got somthig like this ``` ㄰〰0〱㄰〰梩ꥸ9㥨梩ꥸ䥔呁S卉䥔呁\u0000\u0000E䔀\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000䔰〰C䍅䔰〰〰〰0〰〰〰❩楸1ㄧ❩楸㉄䓍1ㄲ㉄䓍\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000G䝏\u0000\u0000G䝏䱅䕚￁셌䱅䕚\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000J䩅\u0000\u0000J䩅灎B䋧灎啅䔀Q兕```

Comment: @iCrashOne, Please in the future, try not put too much code in the comments section, when people asks for detail or more code they are expecting that the question body will be amended. As the question owner, you can modify your post using the EDIT link bellow the question.